# ScrollViewer is displaying but not moving in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am having a problem that I want to include an `ScrollViewer` in my wpf application I used `ScrollViewer` property but it is just showing `ScrollBar` on the right side but it do not allow me to move.

My view gets down the `Window` but I do not able to see that. My code is:

```
<ScrollViewer >
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="170"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="65"/>
                <!--<ColumnDefinition Width="205"/>-->

            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Label
              Grid.Row="0"
              Grid.ColumnSpan="1"
              HorizontalAlignment="Left"
              Content="IP Configuration:"
              Foreground="Black"
              FontWeight="ExtraBold"
              FontSize="14"
              Opacity="0.8"  
            />

            <Label
             Grid.Row="1"
             Grid.Column="0"
             VerticalAlignment="Center"
             Content="Wireless IP Address"
             Foreground="Black"
             Opacity="0.8"  
             />

            <TextBox
            Grid.Row="1"
            Grid.Column="1"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
           />

            <Label
             Grid.Row="2"
             Grid.ColumnSpan="1"
             HorizontalAlignment="Left"
             Content="AP Group Configuration"
             Foreground="Black"
             FontWeight="ExtraBold"
            FontSize="14"
             Opacity="0.8"  
             />
            <Label
             Grid.Row="3"
             Grid.Column="0"
             VerticalAlignment="Center"
             Content="Group ID"
             Foreground="Black"
             Opacity="0.8"  
             Margin="0,0,0,5"
             />

            <TextBox
            Grid.Row="3"
            Grid.Column="1"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            Margin="0,0,0,5"
           />

            <Label
             Grid.Row="3"
             Grid.Column="2"
             VerticalAlignment="Center"
             Content="(1-1024)"
             Foreground="Black"
             Opacity="0.8"  
             Margin="0,0,0,5"
             />

            <Label
             Grid.Row="4"
             Grid.Column="0"
             VerticalAlignment="Center"
             Content="AP Hardware Type"
             Foreground="Black"
             Opacity="0.8"  
             />

            <ComboBox
            Grid.Row="4"
            Grid.Column="1"
            >
                <ComboBoxItem >0-Any</ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem>21-ARC1000MAP , Indoor Radio b/g/n</ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem>22-ARC2000MAP , Dual Radio a/n, b/g/n</ComboBoxItem>
            </ComboBox>

            <Button
            Grid.Row="4"
            Grid.Column="2"
            Margin="10,0,0,0"
            Style="{StaticResource AppButtons}">
                Add
            </Button>

            <TextBox 
            Grid.Row="5"
            Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
            IsReadOnly="True"
            IsEnabled="False"
            Visibility="Hidden"
            Height="10"/>

            <DataGrid Grid.Row="6"
                  Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Width="100"  Header="Group ID" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="AP Hardware Type"/>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>

            <Label
             Grid.Row="7"
             Grid.Column="0"
             HorizontalAlignment="Left"
             Content="Network Configuration"
             FontWeight="ExtraBold"
             Foreground="Black"
            FontSize="14"
             Opacity="0.8"  
             />

            <Label
             Grid.Row="8"
             Grid.Column="0"
             VerticalAlignment="Center"
             Content="SSID"
             Foreground="Black"
             Opacity="0.8"  
             />

            <TextBox
            Grid.Row="8"
            Grid.Column="1"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            Text="Guest Network"
           />

            <Label
             Grid.Row="9"
             Grid.Column="0"
             VerticalAlignment="Center"
             Content="Security"
             Foreground="Black"
             Opacity="0.8"  
             />

            <ComboBox 
                Grid.Row="9"
                Grid.Column="1"
                ItemsSource="{Binding ACAvailableSecurityTypes}"
                SelectedItem="{Binding ACSelectedSecurityType}"
                >

            </ComboBox>

            <view:ACSecurityStaticWEP
                Grid.Row="10"
                Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                Visibility="{Binding IsACStaticWep, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"/>

        </Grid>
        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: What is the parent of `ScrollViewer`?

Comment: All the controls are inside ScrollViewer ,ScrollViewer itself behaving as parent control!

Comment: So `ScrollViewer` is placed directly in the `Window`?

Comment: Yes it worked i packed my ScrollViewer inside another Grid and ScrollBar starts moving now ...thanks

Comment: @CodeSniper Dint my solution work?

Comment: @Sajeetharan nope i tried it very firstly because it seemed to be a good solution but unfortunately it didnt work:(

Comment: @CodeSniper No it should work because i have tried your code! did you set the height for the StackPanel

Comment: @Sajeetharan ok i will try it again tomorrow

Comment: @Sajeetharan Where you have tried i am using usercontrol!

Comment: @CodeSniper Yes i tried with usercontrol, will post the complete code, check

Answer (score 1):

Your `ScrollViewer` height is infinite, set it to any value and that should do it

Comment: Can you give an example i tried but it did not work!

Answer (score 0):

You need to set **VerticalScrollBarVisibility**  of ScrollViewer

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto >
```

Also your **StackPanel** **Height** property Should have some value

```
<StackPanel Height="500" Width="376"  Orientation="Vertical"  >
```

**Complete Code:**

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" >
            <StackPanel Height="700" Orientation="Vertical" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="170"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="65"/>
                        <!--<ColumnDefinition Width="205"/>-->

                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <Label
              Grid.Row="0"
              Grid.ColumnSpan="1"
              HorizontalAlignment="Left"
              Content="IP Configuration:"
              Foreground="Black"
              FontWeight="ExtraBold"
              FontSize="14"
              Opacity="0.8"  
            />

                    <Label
             Grid.Row="1"
             Grid.Column="0"
             VerticalAlignment="Center"
             Content="Wireless IP Address"
             Foreground="Black"
             Opacity="0.8"  
             />

                    <TextBox
            Grid.Row="1"
            Grid.Column="1"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
           />

                    <Label
             Grid.Row="2"
             Grid.ColumnSpan="1"
             HorizontalAlignment="Left"
             Content="AP Group Configuration"
             Foreground="Black"
             FontWeight="ExtraBold"
            FontSize="14"
             Opacity="0.8"  
             />
                    <Label
             Grid.Row="3"
             Grid.Column="0"
             VerticalAlignment="Center"
             Content="Group ID"
             Foreground="Black"
             Opacity="0.8"  
             Margin="0,0,0,5"
             />

                    <TextBox
            Grid.Row="3"
            Grid.Column="1"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            Margin="0,0,0,5"
           />

                    <Label
             Grid.Row="3"
             Grid.Column="2"
             VerticalAlignment="Center"
             Content="(1-1024)"
             Foreground="Black"
             Opacity="0.8"  
             Margin="0,0,0,5"
             />

                    <Label
             Grid.Row="4"
             Grid.Column="0"
             VerticalAlignment="Center"
             Content="AP Hardware Type"
             Foreground="Black"
             Opacity="0.8"  
             />

                    <ComboBox
            Grid.Row="4"
            Grid.Column="1"
            >
                        <ComboBoxItem >0-Any</ComboBoxItem>
                        <ComboBoxItem>21-ARC1000MAP , Indoor Radio b/g/n</ComboBoxItem>
                        <ComboBoxItem>22-ARC2000MAP , Dual Radio a/n, b/g/n</ComboBoxItem>
                    </ComboBox>

                    <Button
            Grid.Row="4"
            Grid.Column="2"
            Margin="10,0,0,0">


                    </Button>

                    <TextBox 
            Grid.Row="5"
            Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
            IsReadOnly="True"
            IsEnabled="False"
            Visibility="Hidden"
            Height="10"/>

                    <DataGrid Grid.Row="6"
                  Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                        <DataGrid.Columns>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Width="100"  Header="Group ID" />
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="AP Hardware Type"/>
                        </DataGrid.Columns>
                    </DataGrid>

                    <Label
             Grid.Row="7"
             Grid.Column="0"
             HorizontalAlignment="Left"
             Content="Network Configuration"
             FontWeight="ExtraBold"
             Foreground="Black"
            FontSize="14"
             Opacity="0.8"  
             />

                    <Label
             Grid.Row="8"
             Grid.Column="0"
             VerticalAlignment="Center"
             Content="SSID"
             Foreground="Black"
             Opacity="0.8"  
             />

                    <TextBox
            Grid.Row="8"
            Grid.Column="1"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            Text="Guest Network"
           />

                    <Label
             Grid.Row="9"
             Grid.Column="0"
             VerticalAlignment="Center"
             Content="Security"
             Foreground="Black"
             Opacity="0.8"  
             />

                    <ComboBox 
                Grid.Row="9"
                Grid.Column="1"
                ItemsSource="{Binding ACAvailableSecurityTypes}"
                SelectedItem="{Binding ACSelectedSecurityType}"
                >

                    </ComboBox>


                </Grid>
            </StackPanel>
        </ScrollViewer>
```

[image]